# CSS float and display:block

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.
не могу добиться, чтобы div отображался как блочный эелемент.

```
<div  style="display:block;">
                <div style="float:left">
                    <img src="/public/content/2.jpg" alt="dddd" class="preview">
                </div>
                <div  style=" float:left; margin: 30px;">
                    ффффф<br/>
                    ыыыыыыы
                </div>
            </div>
<div style="display:block;">
                <div style="float:left">
                    <img src="/public/content/2.jpg" alt="dddd" class="preview">
                </div>
                <div  style=" float:left; margin: 30px;">
                    рррр<br/>
                    фффффф
                </div>
            </div>
```

Проблема в том, что  <div  style="display:block;"> отображаются в строку.
Как заставить отображаться их как блочный элемент страницы?

Если же у первого блока выставить <div  style="display:inline-block;">, то все отображается как и задумано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделайте

```
<div style="display:block;clear: both;">
```

то что оно блок, еще само по себе не отменяет float :left